# How increase and decrease progress bar with checkbox in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5

[image]

I want when i check each box, progress bar increase %20 and when i unchecked box, progress bar decreased %20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to `QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)` signal, and change the `progressbar` value according to signal `state`.

#### Edit

Following the comments, I will update the answer further more. Like I said you need to connect to `QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)` signal from each `QCheckBox` you have.

To connect to signal you use:

```
connect(ui->checkBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &MainWindow::Update_ProgressBar);
connect(ui->checkBox_2, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &MainWindow::Update_ProgressBar);
...
```

And the `slot` will be:

```
void MainWindow::Update_ProgressBar(int value)
{
    int currentValue = ui->progressBar->value();
    if(value == 0)ui->progressBar->setValue(currentValue - 20);
    else ui->progressBar->setValue(currentValue + 20);
}
```

Comment: I just started this program, I don't know most things exactly, how can I do this?

Comment: I can tell you the answer but you wont learn anything this way, read about [Signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: If you still cant get it comment on this answer and I will reply again after a couple of hours.

Comment: ' void Widget::on_checkBox_2_stateChanged()
{
    ui->progressBar->setValue(40); '    i make this type but If I do not press sequentially ,it suddenly increases.

Comment: where is the  "40" coming from in your slot? I'd expect this to be something passed to the slot from the signal.